# Excel rule/macro that color a cell depending on the its value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have never used macro/rules on Excel. Is it possible with a rule/macro to color a cell depending on its value ?
I have 4 different values : "green", "gray", "orange" and "red". And so i would like to color the cell with the value's color.

[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ucQ.png)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't need macros, you just need conditional formatting. https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/29/use-conditional-formatting-excel/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional formatting -

Highlight the range you want to format and then goto

```
HOME > CONDITIONAL FORMATTING > HIGHLIGHT CELLS RULES > EQUAL TO
```

[image]

Choose a condition, e.g. "Green" and what format to give it:

[image]

In the format drop down there is a custom list you can use to set a tonne of properties:

[image]

Comment: Thanks i did it but i have many sheets do you know how can i apply my 4 CF to all the sheets of the file ?

Comment: Yeah you can copy a cell with conditional formatting applied, then select a range, right-click and choose to paste the FORMAT ONLY.